# Underscores font-size mixin

Tags: css, sass, underscores-wp

I'm using the [underscores starter theme](https://github.com/Automattic/_s) for wordpress.

They have this [mixin](https://github.com/Automattic/_s/blob/master/sass/mixins/_mixins-master.scss#L2) which I've no idea what it's trying to do.

```
// Rem output with px fallback
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 1) {
    font-size: ($sizeValue * 16) * 1px;
    font-size: $sizeValue * 1rem;
}
```

Can someone explain the math behind this?
How can I make use of it if I'm given font sizes in px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It just outputs your font size in `rem` with pixel fallback ('16' is the base font size here).
If you use `@include font-size(1.2)`, it will output:

```
font-size: 19.2px; // fallback for those with no rem support
font-size: 1.2rem;
```

This mixin is not suitable for converting font-size in pixels to rem.
If you want to write your code in pixels and have them converted to rem, the mixin should look something like this:

```
@mixin font-size-px-to-rem($value: 12) {
  font-size: $value * 1px;
  font-size: $value / 16 * 1rem;
}
```

then use it:

```
.test {
  @include font-size-px-to-rem(14);
}
```

which outputs to:

```
.test {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Blimey, that's a bit more abstraction than is needed. It's a little bit of work to swap out, but this is the mixin I use:

```
$base-font-size: 16;

@mixin font-size-rems($target-px-size) {
    $rem-size: $target-px-size / $base-font-size;
    font-size: $target-px-size * 1px;
    font-size: $rem-size * 1rem;
}
```

I then use it like this:

```
.example {
    @include font-size-rems(24);
}
```

Which outputs:

```
.example {
   font-size: 24px;
   font-size: 1.5rem;
}
```